# C# / XNA - Bounding Circle Collision (Micro) Optimization?

Tags: c#, optimization, xna, micro-optimization

I've been working on a simple space shooter, and have gotten to the point in the project where my terribly written code is actually slowing things down. After running EQATEC, I can see that the majority of the problem is in the icky check everything on everything collision detection. I was considering putting in a QuadTree, but the majority of the collisions are on asteroids, which do move around a lot (would require a lot of updating). My next alternative was micro-optimizing the collision check itself. Here it is:

```
    public bool IsCircleColliding(GameObject obj) //simple bounding circle collision detection check
    {
        float distance = Vector2.Distance(this.WorldCenter, obj.WorldCenter);
        int totalradii = CollisionRadius + obj.CollisionRadius;

        if (distance < totalradii)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
```

I've heard that Vector2.Distance involves a costly Sqrt, so is there any way to avoid that? Or is there a way to approximate the distance using some fancy calculation? Anything for more speed, essentially.

Also, slightly unrelated to the actual question, is there a good method (other than QuadTrees) for spatial partitioning of fast-moving objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compute the square of the distance instead of the actual distance, and compare that to the square of the collision threshold. That should be a bit faster. If most asteroids are the same size, you can reuse the same value for the collision threshold without recomputing it.

Another useful trick is to first do a simple check based on bounding boxes, and compute the distance only if the bounding boxes intersect. If they don't, then you know (for cheap) that the two objects aren't colliding.

Comment: Alright, replaced Vector2.Distance with DistanceSquared and multiplied each radius by itself, now the collision radii seem to be thrown out of whack; everything seems to sink into each other. I'll go play around with breakpoints for a bit. :P

Comment: you have to square totalradii, not each radius individually.

Comment: Aaaand now it works. Well, that makes me feel like a dumbass. Thanks.